# current leakage of MacBook Pro?

Tags: hardware

I can feel current leakage on my MacBook Pro when it is being charged. And it seems a lot of people in my country report the same problem.

Is this because of the voltage(220V) we use?

What's the solution?

**UPDATE** I went to Apple Store(Shanghai, China) several hours ago and they refused to do anything. weird company. I bought my MacBook Pro 3 months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely due to an earthing problem. I used to have the same problem on my MacBook Air. To fix it:

1. Ensure that you're using the three pin socket converter.
2. Ensure that the connections are secure enough.
3. Ensure that there is proper earthing in your building.

For me, the problem was #2. I had to replace the (non-Apple) adapter that converts between US and Indian sockets.

220 volts is not the issue. The MacBook adapters are built to support it and the transformer within steps down the voltage appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

The solution for me was to use the **adapter with a *three pin* extension cord**.

Then your notebook is earthed and no more charges stay on the cover that shock you :-). Some Macbooks suffer from insulation failure of the casing. A third contact provides for a connection to earth ground so that net charge can escape the cover. This requires a wall socket with proper earthing.

[image]

Comment: Ah-ha! So that's why my macbook always shocks me. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If you are in an EU region or a country that uses Schuko-type plugs, refer to this.

I found a product with Grounded Plug (duckhead) as shown in the picture below that is a Schuko type for EU.
The grounding function is activated when the Apple Power Adapter ground pin and the plug ground pin are combined.

[image]

It says that you can buy it on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08JYWKTZ3?ref=myi_title_dp&th=1) now.
https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08JYWKTZ3?ref=myi_title_dp&th=1

Doodle Plug is available for Apple MacBook, iPad chargers in EU countries (Germany, France, Spain, the Netherlands, Belgium, Finland, Norway, Sweden, Austria, Greece, etc.).

- Available for all Apple Chargers (Magsafe, USB Power adapters) with
  ground pins
- Anti-static and device protection while charging Apple products
- Compatible with both Schuko type outlets, including the EU and Korea
- Significantly reduce iPad and iPhone touch errors (including Apple
  Pencil) while charging
- Reduces the noise of earphones or speakers when charging